# Change schema on views using Django Tenants

Tags: django, postgresql, django-tenants

I'm using Django Tenants on my project and I'm creating a schema for each Tenant.
I have 'django.contrib.auth' and 'django.contrib.contenttypes' both in SHARED_APPS and in TENANT_APPS, and now I want to create specific groups in each tenant schema.
The problem is that I'm always reading and writing values from the public schema.
I implemented the following:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_tenants.postgresql_backend',
        'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
        'USER': 'DB_USER',
        'PASSWORD': 'DB_PASS',
        'HOST': 'DB_HOST',
        'PORT': 'DB_PORT',
    }
}


DATABASE_ROUTERS = (
    'django_tenants.routers.TenantSyncRouter',
)
```

How can I change to a different schema? Can I do it on an app views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution,

```
from django_tenants.utils import schema_context

my_schema_name = 'volvo'
from django_tenants.utils import schema_context
with schema_context(my_schema_name):
   #do what you want here
```

Basically, it was the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066495/access-public-schema-from-tenant-schema-django-tenant), but with a different library (django-tenants). After checking their [source code](https://github.com/django-tenants/django-tenants), found out that they had the same method.